# searching for a good Windows 10 mail programm

Tags: email, email-client

this is very basic but I haven't found an answer to this yet. 
I have verious reasons why the actual known programs are broken:

- Thunderbird doesn't support conversations very well
- Windows 10 Mail is pretty good, but it has bugs like not recognizing all attachments (not fixed issue for years if you search the net). Also it doesn't cite at all when responding to an e-mail.
- Mailbird is not a normal e-mail client as it seems, I read that privacy-wise one should not touch that

Can you recommend any other program that works correctly, 
that I should have a look at?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You have not mentioned that you want a free email client, so I would suggest the most obvious choice: Outlook. It has tons of great features and tweaks to customize your experience. I have tried other free email clients but nothing matches it.

Comment: I guess you're right -- but, I can only use Outlook 2016

Comment: I am using that too, and I tried the Outlook from Office 365, and frankly, there's not a lot of difference